# How can all of them be irrational ??

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

[image]

> Assume that $\{x,y,x^2,y^2,xy\}$ are all irrational.
>
> Can it be true that all of $\{x-y,x+y,x^2-y^2,x^2+y^2\}$ are irrational?
>
> Details: $|x|\ne|y|$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

In the question above I took $x$ to be $\sqrt{2} + 1$ and $y$ to be $\sqrt{2} - 1$ and thus both are irrational and their squares which are $x^2$ and $y^2$ are also irrational, so I get $x - y = (\sqrt{2} + 1) - ( \sqrt{2} - 1) = 2$ and $x^2 + y^2 = (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2 + ( \sqrt{2} - 1)^2 = 6$ to be rational.

But in the answer above it says none could be rational !! So, do I digress somewhere in my reasoning ?

Comment: In your example $xy$ is not irrational.

Comment: Ahhhh well i forgot.......my bad.....

Comment: @ArnavDas : After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). Thank you!

Comment: @Watson, thanks i didn't knew

Comment: @ArnavDas : no problem! Don't forget to accept the other answers, if you find them useful :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to show that, if any two of
$\{x-y,\; x+y,\; x^2-y^2,\; x^2 + y^2\}$
are rational then that at least one of 
$\{x,\; y,\; x^2,\; y^2,\; xy \}$
is rational. Which means that the answer to the question is no.
There are $6$ ways to choose two objects out of $4$.

### Case 1, 2, and 3: Any two of $\{x-y,\; x+y,\; x^2 - y^2\}$ are rational.

Since $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2 - y^2$, then if any two are rational, then all three are rational. It follows then, that $\dfrac{(x-y)+(x+y)}2 = x$ is rational in all three cases.

### Case 4: $x-y$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are rational

Then $\dfrac{(x^2 + y^2) - (x-y)^2}2 = xy$ is rational.

### Case 5: $x+y$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are rational

Then $\dfrac{(x+y)^2 - (x^2 + y^2)}2 = xy$ is rational.

### Case 6: $x^2-y^2$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are rational

Then $\dfrac{(x^2-y^2) + (x^2 + y^2)}2 = x^2$ is rational.